# Not getting the right answer from celcius to farenheit

Tags: java, associativity

```
static void CToF(float c){

        float f=32+((9/5)*c);
        System.out.printf("%.2f",f);


    }

  public static void main(String[] args) {

        CToF(27);

        sc.close();
    }
```

Here the priority of the  * and **/** same so according to their associativity , it will execute from right to left.

So that 9/5 executed first and after that it multiplies with c so the answer is 80.60 but I got 59.00.

What's the problem?

Comment: Hint: 32+27 = 59

Comment: ya your are right but why it is not considering the 9/5=1.8?

Comment: Because you're dividing integers, so it equals 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I make some change and write like this

float f=32+(c*9/5);

it works.xD

Comment: It works but do you know why?

Comment: No sir, could please explain it in brief ?

Comment: (9/5) is 1 for your compiler. When you declare (c*9/5) the result is casted to float.

Comment: c is a float, making c*9 a float, thus causing floating point division... If you made c an int, it would also not work as expected, and you should be using `27.0f` as the parameter to be more explicit

Comment: @aran ok sir thank you for make it float  I have to make the type casting like this f=32+(((float)9/5)*c)

Comment: @TheGentelmen24 this may be the first time I'm called sir. A simple ((1f*9/5)*c) would work. The good way would be the pointed by OneCricketeer `(9f/5)*c` -- *but i like complicating myself a bit*

Comment: @aran xDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD